# How to clear embedded webview cache in windows phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an embedded webbrowser in my application and i have to clear the cache of the browser.does any one knows the code for clearing the cache of webbrowser in windows phone 7?

Answer (score 1):

You cant clear the cache of a WebBrowser.

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/8b2c3ece-a5fe-4cb9-80a7-70284aebfc58/